# HTML editable table sent as attachement via email

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

I'm using javascript to write a page for my website which will contain an editable table. My clients are suposed to fill out that table and then press a "Send order" button which will send that table to my email address.

Is it possible to do that? I haven't managed to find any tutorials about sending that table to email. I only found how to create that editable table.

Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen any form in an email and I doubt you could because that would be a very heavy mail to load! What you could do is send a link to a form on your website, with a $_GET value so that you can identify the specific order.